# How Bind the Window max & start size to an child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, window

Here is my Test Xaml which doesn't work like expected

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        SizeToContent="Manual"
        Top="150"
        MinHeight="90" MinWidth="90"
             MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=CPresenter, Path=MaxHeight,Mode=OneTime}"
             MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=CPresenter, Path=MaxHeight,Mode=OneTime}"
             Height="{Binding ElementName=CPresenter, Path=Height,Mode=OneTime}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=CPresenter, Path=MaxWidth,Mode=OneTime}">
    <Viewbox Name="viewer" 
             Stretch="Uniform">


        <ContentPresenter Name="CPresenter">
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <UserControl MaxWidth="337" MaxHeight="156">
                    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red"
                      MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="100"/>
                </UserControl>
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
        </ContentPresenter>

    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

the code above should set the Window `MaxWidth` & `Width` to `337` it should also set the `MaxHeight` & `Height` to `156` but non of this bindings seams to work.

There is no Error it just doesn't use the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `Binding` to the `MaxHeight`, etc. properties from the `ContentPresenter` element named `CPresenter`, but you didn't set those properties on that element. You set them on the `UserControl` inside it. Also, you don't need a `ContentPresenter` element there at all. Try this:

```
<Viewbox Name="viewer" Stretch="Uniform">
    <UserControl Name="CPresenter" Width="50" Height="50" MaxWidth="337" 
        MaxHeight="156">
        <Grid Background="Red" />
    </UserControl>
</Viewbox>
```

Obviously, you'll want to change the name of the `UserControl` to something better, but that should work.

Comment: the UserControl is is only known at runtime and if i use snoop to look in to Window the ContentPresenter Width and Height are the same as the ones from my Usercontrol but even binding to this values fails

Comment: ok i'm just stupid i need to set the `{Binding Path=Content.Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` and it get the right binding